# react-native-navigation stucks in "component does not have a componentId"

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

The code is:

```
Navigation.registerComponent("FirstScreenName", () => () =>
 (<FirstScreen componentId="FirstScreen" />));
```

I tried:
- Adding and removing the prop `componentId`
- Making it optional/compulsory
- Setup and not set-up `registerAppLaunchedListener`
- Making the prop static

Bulding is fine, but on run time when the debugger hits this line it will complain that `FirstScreenName` does not have a componentId. However, It really has the prop `componentId` set.